# C Preprocessor output

Tags: c

For `gcc -E sample.c -o sample.i` with the following input C program,

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() {
   printf("hello world\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

the `sample.i` have the following output preceded by `#` symbols and I wonder what the line with `#` exactly means.

```
# 1 "sample.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "sample.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
...
```

Comment: First result on google with query "gcc preprocessor output format".

Comment: `#` followed by a number causes the directives to have no effect. These specifically are indicating where the different macros were define

Comment: `# linenum filename flags`....

Comment: @MartinR Possibly a better question than the one that people are saying it duplicates?

Answer (score 4):

There are comments that help a person identify how the preprocessor expanded the various #include <...> macros and other items.

Reading these lines provides the equivalent of reading the logging messages of the preprocessor as it encounters the macros and expands them.

```
# 1 "sample.c"
```

Start on line one of the input "sample.c"

```
# 1 "<built-in>"
```

Process the built-in c pre-procssor directive (must be an implementation detail), but is presented as a fake "file".

```
# 1 "<command-line>"
```

Process the command line directive (again implementation detail), presented as a fake "file".

```
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
```

Include (at line 1) the stdc-predef.h file, it's the start of the file, suppress warnings permitted for system header files, assure that the symbols are treated like C symbols.

```
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
```

Return from the command line "fake" file.

```
# 1 "sample.c"
```

Back in sample.c.

```
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
```

Now starting with file "stdio.h", suppress permitted system warnings, treat symbols in the file a C symbols.

```
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
```

And so on...

[The documentation is here.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RSStepheni Glad to help.  You're welcome.